# Show whether username or password is incorrect?

Tags: c#, authentication

described and show whether `username` or `password` is incorrect

My current code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\AKO Cc\Desktop\visual\WindowsFormsApplication7\WindowsFormsApplication7\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sql=new SqlCommand("select * from db where username='"+textBox1.Text+"' and password='"+textBox2.Text+"'",con);
        SqlDataReader rs=sql.ExecuteReader();
        if (rs.HasRows) {
            rs.Read();
            string id = rs.GetValue(0).ToString();
            string type = rs.GetValue(3).ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(id + " " + type);
        }
        rs.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your post is missing a question. Please add a detailed question.

Comment: When i Enter Wrong Username or Password , Message Box Show Me Which Wrong Username or Pass  not both together?

Comment: I've normally seen that done as "Username or password is invalid." or similar. Note that you should try the username `' or 1 = 1; -- ` with your application, and then consider using parameterized SQL queries.

Comment: Do you need to show a message if user name or password is wrong? It is not a good way to show password is wrong and user name is wrong as separate errors.

Comment: Neither. Just tell the user the login failed. If you specify whether it was the username or the password that failed you're giving potentially unauthorised users more information than is necessary (that they have a valid username, but invalid password, for instance, so can just brute force the password as they have a valid username already).

Comment: For security reasons it is highly recommended NOT to say if the user or pw is wrong. You always say that the combination of both is wrong. Otherwise it would be easier to hack login data.

Comment: @PrasanthVJ  Yes But I Need show me which one is wrong pass or username? sorry for my english ^_^

Comment: On the plus side, your application doesn't currently require a password :)

Comment: @Parez Dara , In real scenario user name should be unique. So there will be only one password for that user. Fetch the password from database using the input username and compare the db password and input password to show an error.

Comment: As already stated, don't do that. It is a security concern. Also you should not store passwords without some salt! Slugs and hackers do not like salt!

Comment: The maddest case is to say "Password valid, user name is not!". Usernames are often easy to find out/guess. Try the most common passwords until you get a hit and then cycle through usernames.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have a *vulnerable* design: when `db` table is stolen *all* logins/passwords are compromized. Do not store *password*, but its *hash*.

Next, let's *extract a method* (separate *business logic* - credentail validation and *UI* - `TextBox`es):

```
   // static: we don't want form's instance: "this"
   private static bool IsCredentialValid(string login, string password) {
     //TODO: do not hardcode the connection string, but load it 
     // new SqlConnection() - do not cache conections, but create them
     // using - do not forget to free resources
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"...")) {
       // Make Sql readable and parametrized
       string sql = 
         @"select 1 -- we don't want to fetch any data
             from db
            where [UserName] = @UserName and
                  [Password] = @Password";

       using (SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
         //TODO: better to specify params' types via Parameters.Add(...)
         q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", login); 
         q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);  

         using (SqlDataReader reader = q.ExecuteReader()) {
           // Credential is valid if we have at least one record read
           return reader.Read();
         } 
       } 
     }
   }
```

Then you can easily use it:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if (IsCredentialValid(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text)) {
       // username and password are correct 
     }
     else {
       // username or password is incorrect 
     }
   }
```

Comment: @ParezDara: This answer also contains the use of parameters to avoid SQL injections. It might not be as security critical in a WinForms application as in a website but it's better to start the habit of using them wherever possible early.